# asp-route-id always pass id as query parmeter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying pass id as route parameter by asp-route-id always pass as a query parameter
and I don't want to use href

```
<a asp-area="Employe" asp-controller="PersonManager" asp-action="UserDetails" asp-route-id="@Model.Provider.Id">details</a>
```

the route is like this

```
https://localhost:5002/Employe/PersonManager/UserDetails?id=b4065ff6-c7bd-4244-a6b6-9bc6b7b4c7a8
```

but I want be like this

```
https://localhost:5002/Employe/PersonManager/UserDetails/b4065ff6-c7bd-4244-a6b6-9bc6b7b4c7a8
```

and this is my action

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserDetails([FromRoute] Guid id)
    {
        var user = await _service.GetOneUser(id);

        return View(user);
    }
```

and I don't want change fromRoute to fromQuery it must be FromRoute

Comment: Do include your controller action

Comment: of course thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Id as part of the route, you need to define it as part of the `HttpGet` attribute.

```
[HttpGet("UserDetails/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserDetails([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
    var user = await _service.GetOneUser(id);
    return View(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the route for `HttpGet`:

```cs
[HttpGet("UserDetails/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserDetails([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
    var user = await _service.GetOneUser(id);

    return View(user);
}
```